# Count a frequency of a particular character in Java

Tags: java

I have the following code. What I want to do is count the frequency of a specific character, but I am unable to do it. Could anyone offer any hints?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class Mywork {

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        try {
            String str;
            System.out.println("Enter a String:");
            DataInputStream d=new DataInputStream(System.in);
            str=d.readLine();
            int count=0;
            System.out.println("You Entered  "+str);
            char a[]=new char[str.length()];
            int i=0;
            System.out.println("enetr the characte of which frequency is to be count:");
            char c=(char)d.read();
            System.out.println("you entered "+c);
            while(str!=null){
                if(str.charAt(i)==c){
                    count++;
                } else {
                    i++;
                }
                i++;
            }   
            System.out.println("Frequency of character "+c+"is "+count);
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("I/O Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first `i++` is extraneous.

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition will be to check if `i` is still less than the length of the string (which is the last-index+1). So, replace

```
while(str!=null)
```

with

```
while (i < str.length())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
public static int countOccurance(String inputString, String key) {
    int index = 0;
    int fromIndex = 0;
    int result = 0;

    if (inputString == null || key == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    while ((index = inputString.indexOf(key, fromIndex)) != -1) {
        result++;
        fromIndex = index + key.length;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your loop, you don't need the else section.

```
 while(i < str.length()){
     if(str.charAt(i)==c){
         count++;
     } 
     i++;
 }
```

also need to change str!=null to i < str.length() as suggested by Thrustmaster

Just curious why are you using DataInputStream.readLine. I see that has been deprecated.